# update history in suse repo

Tags: python-3.x, opensuse, zypper

is there a command to list package updates or history of a repo with **zypper**?
i'm mainly trying to find out when python 3.10 was added to **SLES-15-SP4** repo/module.

most info i could get was using:

```
server: # zypper pa -ir 28
```

but that only returned info about the python packages currently in my python module but not what previous versions existed or specifically when the python310 was added to that repo/module